# Is it possible to use LIKE with a set of strings instead of a single element?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have a list of proper names (in a table), and another table with a free-text field. I want to check whether that field contains any of the proper names. If it were just one, I could do

```
WHERE free_text LIKE "%proper_name%"
```

but how do you do that for an entire list? Is there a better string function I can use with a list?

Thanks

Comment: Just loop through the proper names is how i would do it.

Comment: Without a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, this question is difficult to answer. There's a large suggestion displayed when you add the [tag:sql] that suggests that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS because functionality and syntax differs between them. The suggestion is there for a reason; you should [edit] your post and add that tag now. Without it, you're making it take longer for you to get an answer and wasting the time of people who try to answer only to find out it won't work on your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

No, `like` does not have that capability.

Many databases support regular expressions, which enable to you do what you want.  For instance, in Postgres this is phrased as:

```
where free_text ~ 'name1|name2|name3'
```

Many databases also have full-text search capabilities that speed such searches.

Both capabilities are highly specific to the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `LIKE` in a standard `JOIN`, but the query most likely will be slow, because it will search each proper name in each `free_text`.

For example, if you have 10 proper names in a list and a certain `free_text` value contains the first name, the server will continue processing the rest of 9 names.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT  -- DISTINCT
    free_text_table.*
FROM
    free_text_table
    INNER JOIN proper_names_table ON free_text_table.free_text LIKE proper_names_table.proper_name
;
```

If a certain `free_text` value contains several proper names, that row will be returned several times, so you may need to add `DISTINCT` to the query. It depends on what you need.

---

It is possible to use `LATERAL JOIN` to avoid Cartesian product (where each row in `free_text_table` is compared to each rows in `proper_names_table`). The end result may be faster, than the simple variant. It depends on your data distribution.

Here is SQL Server syntax.

```
SELECT
    free_text_table.*
FROM
    free_text_table
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            proper_names_table.proper_name
        FROM proper_names_table
        WHERE free_text_table.free_text LIKE proper_names_table.proper_name
        -- ORDER BY proper_names_table.frequency
    ) AS A
;
```

Here we don't need `DISTINCT`, there will be at most one row in the result for each row from `free_text_table` (one or zero). Optimiser should be smart enough to stop reading and processing `proper_names_table` as soon as the first match is found due to `TOP(1)` clause.

If you also can somehow order your proper names and put those that are most likely to be found first, then the query is more likely to be faster than a simple `JOIN`. (Add a suitable `ORDER BY` clause in subquery).